# jQuery animate with hover is only working on hover once but not subsequent

Tags: jquery

Any ideas what might cause a conflict that would prevent the second callback function on jQuery hover and then subsequently prevent the first from running any additional times?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(".nav ul ul").css({ display: 'none' });
        $(".nav ul li").hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
                .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "show", "opacity": "show" }, 600 );
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
                .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "hide", "opacity": "hide" }, 600 );
        });

    });
```

Comment: Works fine for me. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R47FJ/

Comment: I tested it elsewhere to and it worked. In the current environment I have it in, it's not working. Looking for suggestions on what to look for as a conflict that would stop it half way through like that.

Comment: Did you check if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: @strah Yes. Thanks though. No errors and no warnings. It's baffling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. There was conflict in the css file. Once the hover function was used once there was a css style:

```
ul.nav li:hover > ul,
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This was overriding the jQuery and just displaying the dropdown in block style quickly without animate.